# Why does my trigger event in WPF not work?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and I am trying to make a  trigger event with Radio Buttons that whenever I check one Radio Button something will happen like changing the background or something else. Here is what I have:

```
<Border Width="157" Height="35" Margin="0 30 0 0" Background="#181F26" CornerRadius="3">
            <Viewbox Height="29">

                <RadioButton  
                    Click="rb_storno_Click"
                    x:Name="rb_storno"
                    Content="Storno"
                    FontSize="25"
                    Foreground="#BED9FF" 
                    FontFamily="Century Gothic" 
                    Background="#2683FF"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    BorderBrush="#1D5BAC"                            
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                    Margin="5,2,5,2">

                    <RadioButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RadioButton.Style>
                    
                </RadioButton>
            </Viewbox>


        </Border>
```

But it isn't working, any suggestions on how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set initial Foreground value via setter:

```
<RadioButton
    Click="rb_storno_Click"
    x:Name="rb_storno"
    Content="Storno"
    FontSize="25"
    FontFamily="Century Gothic" 
    Background="#2683FF"
    BorderThickness="2"
    BorderBrush="#1D5BAC"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
    Margin="5,2,5,2">

    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#BED9FF"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
    
</RadioButton>
```

currently you set local value. Due to [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list), a Style cannot override it.

Comment: Still dosnt work

Comment: Are you sure you removed the `Foreground="#BED9FF" ` from the RadioButton attributes?

Comment: Oh yeah i forget it thanks for your help, now its working