# I want to know why my togglebutton is not allowing me to change the button color after pressed?

Tags: wpf, xaml, togglebutton

I am trying to change color on the togglebutton's background after being clicked/pressed.

Here is the sample code I used:

my goal for the togglebutton is to show ##342350 (dark purple) after being clicked/pressed (to activate) then back to normal color #FF505050 (Gray) *Deactivated by clicking button again*

```xml
<ToggleButton
    x:Name="Video_Capture"
    Background="#FF505050"
    BorderBrush="#FF505050"
    FontFamily="Arial"
    FontSize="17"
    Foreground="White">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border
                            Padding="1,1,60,1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter Width="162" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#342350"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF505050"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF505050"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#342350"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#342350"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Video Capture is OFF" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Video Capture is ON" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#342350" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

any tips or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I did a lot of research on the how but most of them does not work for some reason so im baffled on the how or why it won't work at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410754/why-does-my-trigger-event-in-wpf-not-work

Comment: Ispressed only applies for the brief period the mouse is down as you click. You need ischecked. You also cannot set a background value like you do in the tag. Set it in a style or it cannot be overridden by a trigger.

Comment: @Andy,

So I have to set it in style?

like this?

                        `<Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Video Capture is ON" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#342350" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>`

Comment: Like css there is a property precedence. If you specifically set a value like you currently do Background="#FF505050" then you cannot override that with a trigger.

Comment: @Andy

it uses .cs* 

        private void Video_Capture_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Background = "#FF505050";
        }

Comment: can you provide your version of sample with my code?